# Making Foundation Interchanges Load Partials in Wordpress

Tags: zurb-foundation

I've been using Underscore to create a Wordpress theme. I'd like to use Data-Interchange to swap out layouts for mobile and desktop viewport sizes. When using an adding an image on a small screen (via interchange), the image shows up as it supposed to. However when attempting to change layouts based on viewport size - chrome's dev tools give me a 404 for the page.

The image and the .php page both have the same ownership and permissions. I've used [this page as a guide](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/493-interchange-with-wordpress) but, still cannot get this to work.

Even if I change the .php file to .html, I still get a 404 on either.

Also, the .php file shows up as an XHR while the image shows up as text/html.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Let's see your markup (not the linked example).

Comment: @Aibrean - Thanks for checking this out. I've actually moved on from this using the interchange method to swap out templates because I could not get it to work for .php pages. However, I would still like to get it to work someday. My markup hardly varied from the markup in the link. As I stated above, I could get images to work but not .php pages. Have you seen this problem before when using Wordpress and Foundation?

Comment: You aren't using a child theme by chance? I always use stylesheet directory in my code.

Comment: And did you add `<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
?>` to the end?

Comment: @Aibrean - I'm not using a child theme. Underscore is a barebones theme. I also added the require line as well. The best I can get is a change from a 404 error to a 500. The image interchange shows up on the page but, the partial just gives a 500. WP's debug log show nothing.